# Rooting Xperia tipo

Tags: rooting, sony-xperia-tipo

I've unlocked my bootloader. After all the set-up, I tried to root my Tipo using Bin4ry Root's package. It didn't work; it gave me an error like `permission denied (are you root?)`. Later, it said "successful", but it's not rooted.

I want to root it because Apex Launcher has an option that allows you to use the device's own widgets if the device is rooted. If there is any other way to use the device's original widgets on the launchers, I may not bother rooting it.

Comment: I took the freedom to link your question into our [rooting master index](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/16575). You might want to visit that page and check for available rooting methods mentioned there, maybe there's one working for your device (don't forget to update your question here in that case).